# Get all parameter in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following JavaScript JSON array of real estate home objects

```
var json = {
    'homes': [{
    "home_name": "tiger",
            "home_id": "1",
            "price": "925",
            "sqft": "1100",
            "num_of_beds": "2",
            "num_of_baths": "2.0",
        }, {
    "home_name": "lion",
            "hom`enter code here`e_id": "2",
            "price": "1425",
            "sqft": "1900",
            "num_of_beds": "4",
            "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        },  
    {
    "home_name": "kingkong",
            "home_id": "3",
            "price": "1425",
            "sqft": "1900",
            "num_of_beds": "4",
            "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        },


    ]
}
```

what i want to have is to display a new array that would appear like this

```
console.log(newarray);
```

// [tiger, lion, kingkong]

hope that someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
var json = {
    'homes': [{
    "home_name": "tiger",
            "home_id": "1",
            "price": "925",
            "sqft": "1100",
            "num_of_beds": "2",
            "num_of_baths": "2.0",
        }, {
    "home_name": "lion",
            "home_id": "2",
            "price": "1425",
            "sqft": "1900",
            "num_of_beds": "4",
            "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        },  
    {
    "home_name": "kingkong",
            "home_id": "3",
            "price": "1425",
            "sqft": "1900",
            "num_of_beds": "4",
            "num_of_baths": "2.5",
        },


    ]
}

var newarray = json.homes.map(function(value){return value.home_name});
              
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newarray, 0,4)
```